# Getting Error on merging in VSTS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

[VSTS merging error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC6BC.png)

Getting Error on merging local file with server file

Comment: Link on VSTS merging error to see the image.!

Comment: Can you show the screen shot of the source control explorer? And what's the source branch and target branch separately? And does there has pending changes or changes in shelves for tartget branch or source branch?

Comment: And do you use TFS or VSTS?